# (HTML)(CSS) Why does the left side of my multi-column layout appear smaller than the other?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/drqjmssy/

From the jsfiddle link, I am trying to have "div class='main_content'" be the same vertical height as the "div class='sidebar'". How does one accomplish that? If you can't load the fiddle or it's awful formatting, here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>My project</title>
    <style>

        body {
            background-color: #5A4E3C;
            color: #E9EBBF;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #D8E472;
            padding: 2%;
        }

        nav {
            background-color: #D8E472;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: #D8E472;
            padding: 2%;
            color: #5A4E3C;
        }   

        h1 {
            color: #5A4E3C;
        }

        li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        nav > ul {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .wrapper {
            width: 85%;
            background-color: #418E8E;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .main_content {
            width: 56%;
            padding: 2%;
            column-count: 1;
            float: left;
            background-color: #418E8E;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .sidebar {
            width: 36%;
            padding: 2%;
            column-count: 1;
            float: left;
            background-color: #418E8E;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <div class='wrapper'>

        <header>
            <h1>Main Heading</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='1.html'>Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href='2.html'>Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class='main_content'>
            <article>
                <h2>Subhead</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </article>
        </div>

        <div class='sidebar'>
            <article>
                <h2>Subhead</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </article>
        </div>

    <footer>
        &copy Yazen 2018.
    </footer>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if any of this is confusing./////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the elements in a new tag (I've used `section`) and add `display: flex`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #5A4E3C;
  color: #E9EBBF;
}

header {
  background-color: #D8E472;
  padding: 2%;
}

nav {
  background-color: #D8E472;
}

footer {
  background-color: #D8E472;
  padding: 2%;
  color: #5A4E3C;
}

h1 {
  color: #5A4E3C;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav>ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: #418E8E;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main_content {
  width: 56%;
  padding: 2%;
  column-count: 1;
  float: left;
  background-color: #418E8E;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 36%;
  padding: 2%;
  column-count: 1;
  float: left;
  background-color: #418E8E;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

  <header>
    <h1>Main Heading</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='1.html'>Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='2.html'>Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <div class='main_content'>
      <article>
        <h2>Subhead</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class='sidebar'>
      <article>
        <h2>Subhead</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    &copy Yazen 2018.
  </footer>

</div>
```